# Type inference not working in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, type-inference, collectors

I have newly started off with Java 8 and I'm trying out some examples on Collectors. I'm following the book, Java 8 in action. I have got a doubt regarding type inference :

I have used basic model classes Student, Name to create examples. PFB the details:

```
package com.learning.fundamentals;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Student {
    public enum Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE;
    }
    private String id;
    private Name name;
    private Gender gender;
    public Student(String id, Name name, Gender gender) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public Name getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((gender == null) ? 0 : gender.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Student other = (Student) obj;
        if (gender != other.gender)
            return false;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", gender=" + gender
                + "]";
    }

}

package com.learning.fundamentals;

public class Name {
    private String firstName;
    private String middleName;
    private String lastName;
    public Name(String firstName, String middleName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleName = middleName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result
                + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((lastName == null) ? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
        result = prime * result
                + ((middleName == null) ? 0 : middleName.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Name other = (Name) obj;
        if (firstName == null) {
            if (other.firstName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!firstName.equals(other.firstName))
            return false;
        if (lastName == null) {
            if (other.lastName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!lastName.equals(other.lastName))
            return false;
        if (middleName == null) {
            if (other.middleName != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!middleName.equals(other.middleName))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name [firstName=" + firstName + ", middleName=" + middleName
                + ", lastName=" + lastName + "]";
    }

}
```

Now I have a list of Students like this

```
List<Student> studentList = getStudents(); //some method to create the list
```

Now, let's try out an grouping example. This is a multilevel grouping, first I'm grouping it using Gender and then  some criteria on first name (not important). Here is the code :

```
Map<Student.Gender, Map<String, List<Student>>> studentsByGenderName = 
                                     studentList.stream()
                                                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGender,
                                                        Collectors.groupingBy(std ->  std.getName().getFirstName().substring(0, 4))));
```

This gives me an error at the second collector, stating "The method getName() is undefined for the type Object". Now, I was able to resolve the issue by providing the type of 'std' like this:

```
 Map<Student.Gender, Map<String, List<Student>>> studentsByGenderName = 
                                 studentList.stream()
                                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGender,
                                                    Collectors.groupingBy((Student std) ->  std.getName().getFirstName().substring(0, 4))));
```

My question is why can't java infer the type of the argument in lambda expression used in the second collector while it's able to do that for the first collector?

Comment: Hmm I can't reproduce your compile error with Eclipse Mars.2 or JDK 1.8.0_74.

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.8.0_65 Eclipse Luna

Comment: Is there an error when compiling explicitly with JDK 1.8.0_65? If not, I think you should just upgrade your Eclipse.

Comment: Luna is very buggy with type inference.

Comment: I have not tried with any other version. But, were you able to get the code running without providing the type for 'std'? strange :(

Comment: hey, i used an online tool to run the same code. It ran successfully. Stupidly wasted my time. Thanks!!